# Running MPI program with multiple inputs files and number of processes

Tags: c, awk, mpi

I want to run my mpi program with 3 command line inputs.

```
mpirun -np 4 ./exe file_1 file_2 Size
```

for each `file_1` there is associated `file_2` and `Size` is same for each pair of files. I want to execute my program with the different number of processes say -np  2,4,6,8 and 10.
I have more than a hundred files. I want to execute my code once from command line that reads these files one by one with the specified number of processes.

For serial code, I have tried the following command and it works by taking all .txt files one by one.

```
find . -name "*.txt" | awk -F"/" '{system ("./a.out " $2)}'
```

I am not sure how I can execute with three program line inputs(file1,file2,size) at same time with different number of processes.

Comment: what do you want to achieve ? run two independent simulations simulatneously ? is `exe` a MPI application ?

Comment: yes exe is mpi application. same program needs 3 comman line arguments. 2 input files (file1 and file2) and third argument is size. I want to run the mpi program just once for all 100 files.

Comment: I do not understand how the `MPI` case is different from the `serial` case.

Comment: In the serial case single input file is read and executed but for MPI program it needs two input files during single execution. then next 2 files and so on.

Comment: can you then post a sample command line and the expected behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question, you might for example use:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 -n2 -J% -- mpirun -np4 ./exe % $SIZE
```

If your working directory would contain for example files `a.txt`, `b.txt`, `c.txt`, `d.txt`, this would launch commands:

```
mpirun -np4 ./exe a.txt b.txt $SIZE
mpirun -np4 ./exe c.txt d.txt $SIZE
```

Here, `find` first finds all `*.txt` files in the current directory, outputs their names as null-delimited strings and pipes this list to `xargs`. The `-0` option of `xargs` specifies that it should expect null-delimited input, `-n2` says that it should take two files at a time, and `-J%` prescribes the replacement character `%`, i.e., the character which will be in the supplied command replaced with the file names taken from the input. Finally, `--` merely denotes end of options and is followed by the command to be executed (containing the replacement character).

Comment: I want to ask what if we need to read 2 files with different extension e.g. a.txt and a.mtx similarly b.txt and b.mtx. what needs to be channge here    
     find . -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 -n2 -J% -- mpirun -np4 ./exe % 
     $SIZE